# How to remove Underline from anchor link of a pdf in fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

we are making a pdf report by using FPDF in which we have links.

our problem is that we are not able to remove underline and default color from the link we have sent in the pdf report. and we want to set a custom different color on different links.

below is what we are making.

$text22 = preg_replace('/\S*\b('. $searchphrase[$rr] .')\b\S*/i', '**$1**', $aaa);

> $text22 = preg_replace('/\S*\b('. $searchphrase[$rr] .')\b\S*/i', '**$1**', $aaa);
>
> $pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($main));

below is our pdf report, now we have to remove underline from from the link and set custom color on that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have to extend the FPDF class yourself and change the underline / colour in the *PutLink* function.

http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script50.php

**Edit**

Here's a code sample of extending the FPDF class.  In fact, as the WriteHTML function isn't in the FPDF class, this extends the class which has it in instead.  This is one of many ways to make it work.  In this example you have to specify the link colour in an additional attribute (*data-color*), as the class can't read CSS rules.  You could of course write a regex to parse the CSS, and then translate the colours into r,g,b.  But for a simpler example, I left that out.

```html
<?php

// This class extends the Tutorial 6 class, which in turn extends the main FPDF class
class XPDF extends PDF
{
  protected $clr = "";

  function OpenTag($tag, $attr)
  {
   parent::OpenTag($tag, $attr);
    if ($tag == "A")
    {
      if (isset($attr['DATA-COLOR']))
      {
        
        $this->clr = $attr['DATA-COLOR'];  
      }
      else
      {
        $this->clr = "";
      }
    }
  }
  
  function CloseTag($tag)
  {
    parent::CloseTag($tag);
    if ($tag == "A")
      $this->clr = "";
  }

  function PutLink($URL, $txt)
  {
      // Put a hyperlink
      if ($this->clr != "")
      {
        $clrs = explode(",", $this->clr);
        $this->SetTextColor($clrs[0], $clrs[1], $clrs[2]);
      }
      else
      {
        $this->SetTextColor(0,0,255);
      }
   $this->SetStyle('U',true);
   $this->Write(5,$txt,$URL);
   $this->SetStyle('U',false);
   $this->SetTextColor(0);
  }
}

$html = 'This is some text and <a href="http://www.whatever.com">here is a link</a>.  To specify the pdf colour of a link, you need to specify it as RGB numbers in a data-attribute, like <a href="http://www.whatever.com" data-color="255,0,0">this</a> or <a href="http://www.whatever.com" data-color="255,0,100">this</a>.';

$pdf = new XPDF();
// First page
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',14);
$pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: we have already made links through anchor tag but we want to remove underline and change the color of the anchor tag. kindly suggest.

Comment: Yes. Look into extending the FPDF class and override the PutLink function. Let me know what you don't understand of that and I'll clarify.

Comment: $text22 = preg_replace('/\S*\b('. $searchphrase[$rr] .')\b\S*/i', '<b><a style="text-decoration:none; color:red;" href='http://www.infokartindia.com/test'>$1</a></b>', $aaa);  This code when we run on browser runs fine, but when we are passing $text22 in pdf as $pdf->WriteHTML(utf8_decode($text22));  the css style not working. All the anchors are in blue color and underlined, but we want all the anchor in different color and not underlined.

Comment: Can we add third attribute to the function PutLink like this. 
   function PutLink($URL, $txt,$color1)
{
    // Put a hyperlink
    $this->SetTextColor($color1);
    $this->SetStyle('U',false);
    $this->Write(5,$txt,$URL);
    $this->SetStyle('U',false);
    $this->SetTextColor(0);
}

Comment: I have added code in the answer above to show you one way of doing this, which requires you specifying the colour per link in the <a> tag.

Comment: Thanks for help. we have applied this and it's working in same way as we want. @dan

Comment: hi, we have one more query, we want to justify the text in writeHTML();  please suggest!

Comment: I think this would require a bit more work, as the WriteHTML calls the Write method, which can't do justify. You probably can do it by rewriting the WriteHTML function.